# How to make writer initiated for every job instance in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am writing a spring batch job. I am implementing custom writer using  `KafkaClientWriter extends AbstractItemStreamItemWriter<ProducerMessage>`

I have fields which need to be unique for each instance. But I could see this class initiated only once. Rest jobs have same instance of writer class. 
Where as my custom readers and processors are getting initiated for each job. 
Below is my job configurations. How can I achieve the same behavior for writer as well?

```
 @Bean
        @Scope("job")
        public ZipMultiResourceItemReader reader(@Value("#{jobParameters[fileName]}") String fileName, @Value("#{jobParameters[s3SourceFolderPrefix]}") String s3SourceFolderPrefix, @Value("#{jobParameters[timeStamp]}") long timeStamp, com.fastretailing.catalogPlatformSCMProducer.service.ConfigurationService confService) {
            FlatFileItemReader faltFileReader = new FlatFileItemReader();
            ZipMultiResourceItemReader zipReader = new ZipMultiResourceItemReader();
            Resource[] resArray = new Resource[1];
            resArray[0] = new FileSystemResource(new File(fileName));
            zipReader.setArchives(resArray);
            DefaultLineMapper<ProducerMessage> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<ProducerMessage>();
            lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer());
            CSVFieldMapper csvFieldMapper = new CSVFieldMapper(fileName, s3SourceFolderPrefix, timeStamp, confService);
            lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(csvFieldMapper);
            faltFileReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
            zipReader.setDelegate(faltFileReader);
            return zipReader;
        }

        @Bean
        @Scope("job")
        public ItemProcessor<ProducerMessage, ProducerMessage> processor(@Value("#{jobParameters[timeStamp]}") long timeStamp) {
            ProducerProcessor processor = new ProducerProcessor();
            processor.setS3FileTimeStamp(timeStamp);
            return processor;
        }

        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties
        public ItemWriter<ProducerMessage> writer() {
            return new KafkaClientWriter();
        }

        @Bean
        public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                          ItemReader reader, ItemWriter writer,
                          ItemProcessor processor, @Value("${reader.chunkSize}")
                          int chunkSize) {
            LOGGER.info("Step configuration loaded with chunk size {}", chunkSize);
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                    .chunk(chunkSize).reader(reader)
                    .processor(processor).writer(writer)
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public StepScope stepScope() {
            final StepScope stepScope = new StepScope();
            stepScope.setAutoProxy(true);
            return stepScope;
        }

        @Bean
        public JobScope jobScope() {
            final JobScope jobScope = new JobScope();
            return jobScope;
        }

        @Bean
        public Configuration configuration() {
            return new Configuration();
        }
```

I tried making the writer with job scope. But in that case open is not getting called. This is where I am doing some initializations.

Comment: Change the return type to `KafkaClientWriter` and add `@Scope("job")`.

Comment: @M. Denium : Superb. Thanks .It worked. Now open and close getting called properly. Between why` @Scope("job")` with return type `ItemWriter<ProducerMessage>` was not working ? I was getting some custom field as null from write method which was supposed to set from open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using java based configuration and a scoped proxy what happens is that the return type of the method is detected and for that a proxy is created. So when you return `ItemWriter` you will get a JDK proxy only implementing `ItemWriter`, whereas your `open` method is on the `ItemStream` interface. Because that interface isn't included on the proxy there is no way to call the method.

Either change the return type to `KafkaClientWriter` or `ItemStreamWriter< ProducerMessage>` (assuming the `KafkaCLientWriter` implements that method). Next add `@Scope("job")` and you should have your `open` method called again with a properly scoped writer.